# Inheriting layouts in Phoenix/Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I need to create a simple hierarchy of layouts for my Phoenix/Elixir application and inherit my templates from different layouts. I know how to do that for a single layout and multiple templates. But how exactly can I inherit one layout from another?

Say, the hierarchy is layout1 -> layout2 -> layout3 and template2(layout2), template3(layout3).

In the documentation there's no mention about that.

**update**:

The base layout is the base layout -- similar to a base class in OOP, it doesn't know of its child-layouts -- **how many there're**, if any. Thus it doesn't make sense to call "render children1" from the base one.

Answer (score 2):

Layouts can be nested by passing a `layout` key in `assigns` when calling render:

```
<%= render @view_module, @view_template, Map.put(assigns, :layout, {MyApp.LayoutView, "nested.html"}) %>
```

Here is the relevant section from the docs for [Phoenix.View.render/3](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.View.html#render/3)

> ### Assigns
>
> Assigns are meant to be user data that will be
>   available in templates.   However there are keys under assigns that
>   are specially handled by   Phoenix, they are:
>
> - `:layout` - tells Phoenix to wrap the rendered result in the
>     given layout. See next section.
>
> The following assigns are reserved, and cannot be set directly:
>
> - `@view_module` - The view module being rendered
> - `@view_template` - The `@view_module`'s template being rendered   ## Layouts   Templates can be rendered within other templates using the `:layout`   option. `:layout` accepts a tuple of the form
>     `{LayoutModule, "template.extension"}`.
>
> To render the template
>   within the layout, simply call `render/3`   using the `@view_module`
>   and `@view_template` assign:
>
> ```
>   <%= render @view_module, @view_template, assigns %>
> ```

---

For 3 layouts, you can do something like:

```
# Controller
render(conn, "index.html", nested_1: "nested_1.html", nested_2: "nested_2.html")

# app.html.eex
<%= render @view_module, @view_template, Map.put(assigns, :layout, {MyApp.LayoutView, assigns.nested_1}) %>

# nested_1.html.eex
<%= render @view_module, @view_template, Map.put(assigns, :layout, {MyApp.LayoutView, assigns.nested_2}) %>

# nested_2.html.eex
<%= render @view_module, @view_template, assigns %>
```

Comment: You can keep nesting your layouts. You will have the same call to render in your nested template to nest another template. You should have `<%= render @view_module, @view_template, assigns %>` in your inner most template.

Comment: `You will have the same call to render in your nested template to nest another template. ` -- my base template doesn't know what templates will be nested into it.

Comment: You can pass it through assigns. For example in your controller:

`render(conn, "index.html", user_layout: {MyApp.LayoutView, "user.html"}, other_layout: {MyApp.LayoutView, "other.html"})`

Comment: what controller? there's no controller associated with a layout. what if I have 20 controllers with 20 actions in each?

Comment: Presumably you have a controller somewhere. You can also populate assigns from a plug, I used a controller action here for demonstrative purposes. Somehow, somewhere in your application, you will have to define what templates and layouts to use. Your question is so abstract that this is the best answer I can give you at the moment.

Comment: in your app.html.eex which is the base layout, you've passed a nested layout. but as I've said, the base layout doesn't know what layouts will be nested into it, if any. there can be many and different or zero depending on a controller and action.

Comment: so what do you say?

Comment: so what do you say?

Answer (score 2):

The way I solved this was to add a helper in the View that renders the parent layout:

```
defmodule MyApp.LayoutView do
  use MyApp.Web, :view

  def base_layout(conn, opts, do: contents) when is_list(opts) do
    render "base.html", [conn: conn, contents: contents] ++ opts
  end
end
```

The "contents" argument in the helper will be whatever you put inside the do/end block, so you can use this inside the HTML for  a "child layout" like:

```
<%= base_layout @conn, [foo: "bar"] do %>

    <div class="sublayout-wrapper">
      <%= render @view_module, @view_template, assigns %>      
    </div>
    <!-- specific footer for sub-layout goes here etc -->

<% end %>
```

And in the base.html layout, I output the `@contents` variable where I need the content to be rendered, like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header"></div>
    <%= @contents %>
</body>
```

It's a bit of a hack but so far it was the best solution I found to the problem.

Note that I also added an `opts` parameter to be able to override some assigns in specific cases (I mostly use this to define html css classes to be appended on `<html>` or `<body>` depending on the sublayout being rendered).

Comment: what if there're 4 layouts in the hierarchy? spaghetti code?